# How can I find an answer when I accidentally closed the window?

Tags: support, answers, search

I was attempting to answer a question on computing $\sin(\pi/n)$, and in the process I needed a reference so I opened another window to find it. When I found what I was looking for I meant to close the second window and migrate back to the first one, but I accidentally closed the first window and can no longer find the question. "Road trip over", as they say.

Is there a way I can trace answers I started so I can try again?

Comment: Two points: There might be a draft saved on the page of the questions. To find the question you could use your browser's history.

Comment: Will that work if I closed the window?

Comment: So you did not actually "close" the question, as in voting to close?  I'd suggest backtracking to the time you accidentally closed **the window**, and perusing through questions posted about that time.

Comment: Can't get there.  Opening a new window and backtracking does not get my back to any closed windows.

Comment: The browser-history part yes (of course it depends on your browser configuration but often you can find a list of all the pages visited in the recent past). For the draft, maybe.

Comment: Perhaps "How can I find an answer I was writing? I have accidentally closed the window" as a title

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The site does have a feature to automatically save drafts of posts. They will be displayed again if you navigate to the relevant page.

Thus you really need to find the question first. Then there you will find the draft in the answer field. (There should be a saved draft there as you had the page open for a while.)

To find the question again I recommend to check your browser history. Most browsers can keep track of the recently visited pages and you can simply find the relevant page there. (Of course you might have disabled that or be in "private" mode but usually you'd be able to find it.)

If this does not work you can just search for the question on the site. Using a keyword you might recall. As suggested in comments by amWhy if you know when the question was asked approximately you can also use that to narrow down the search.

Comment: Found it, thanks!

Comment: I'm glad it was helpful. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: This is regular feature I use on mobile device. Most often due to mathjax preview the browser gets slow and writing an answer becomes difficult. So I just close the whole browser and it launches again to same tabs and I can work on my draft again. This however does not work while editing an existing post. It appears drafts are saved for new posts only.